# Immutable - List.of()

Tags: redux, mocha.js, immutable.js

I'm following this redux tutorial - http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html that uses Immutable, trying to make my own version of the app to better understand Immutable and Redux, and I don't understand why my test is failing. The output from Mocha shows that the expected values are the same but I think the order may be causing the test to fail. However the output of Mocha doesn't show the actual order of the List objects. Is List.of() the correct method for an array of objects?

***core_spec.js***

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {initAlbums, next, rate} from '../src/core';

describe('application logic', () => {

  describe('initAlbums', () => {

    it('adds the albums to the state', () => {
      const state = Map();
      const albums = List.of({'Album 1': null}, {'Album 2': null}, {'Album 3': null});
      const nextState = initAlbums(state, albums);
      expect(nextState).to.deep.equal(Map({
        albums: List.of({'Album 1': null}, {'Album 2': null}, {'Album 3': null})
      }));
    });

  });

});
```

***core.js***

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';

export function initAlbums(state, albums) {
  return state.set('albums', List(albums));
}
```

***Mocha output***

```
  1 failing

  1) application logic initAlbums adds the albums to the state:

      AssertionError: expected 'Map { "albums": List [ [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ] }' to equal 'Map { "albums": List [ [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ] }'
      + expected - actual
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your test:

```
expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
  albums: List.of({'Album 1': null}, {'Album 2': null}, {'Album 3': null})
}));
```

You expected an equal.
Following http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_equal

> equal is the asserts that the target is strictly (===) equal to the
>   given val.

And following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

> An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object.

And that's reason why your test is failed. You should use **.deep** instead
http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep